# Failure to pick up attributes following use of ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder: Iterate Feature Classes

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, spatial-join, select-by-location, iteration

I have a folder containing numerous point shapefiles
(Species occurrence records) and (in a separate folder) a multipolygon
shapefile of small parcels of land. For each species, I need to
extract all the polygons which contain a species occurrence record. As
there are many species, and the process needs to be re-run whenever we
get new occurrence records, I have set up a model that iterates
through an input folder (containing species occurrence record
shapefiles) and runs the process.

The simple model (see attached diagram) is set up as follows: Using
the **Select Layer By Location** tool I select the polygons which contain
the species occurrence points. I then use the **Spatial Join** tool to add
all the information contained in the attribute table of the point
shapefiles (e.g. species name, observation date etc.) to this. The
final output is a multipolygon shapefile, named after the input
species containing the detail of the original species occurrence
records.

If I do this manually one at a time this workflow works perfectly;
however, when I run the model using the **Iterate Feature Classes**
command to iterate through numerous species files in the input folder
the final output does not contain the information from the species
occurrence points. When I open the *Field Map* of the **Spatial Join** tool,
the only fields present are those from the original multipolygon
shapefile! I have tried to troubleshoot and for whatever the reason the “Feature Class” output from the
Iterate Feature Classes command does not have an attribute table…

[image: Model1]

Comment: I've just recreated your model and it worked for me.. You don't have any selections on your polygon layer do you or set a processing extent or are they different coordinate systems?